# when to use getNumericValue

Tags: java

In the code below the output will be identical in both loops. The `getNumericValue` is actually returning the numeric value of `char` if the `char` is a digit so `0..9` it returns `int` value eg. `'0'->0` for other ascii codes it returns their code eg `'a'->10`.

Is there any point in using this method for chars other than digits (as in the example code)?

Any use case? I can't think of any other use case apart form getting the digit value form char.

```
    char ch;
    int i =1;
    for(  ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z' ; i++, ch++ )
        System.out.println(ch+" "+i);
    i=1;
    for( int j=Character.getNumericValue('a'); j<= Character.getNumericValue('z'); j++,i++  )
        System.out.println(i+ " "+j);
```

EDIT
Only non trivial example is for example, the character '\u216C' (the roman numeral fifty) will return an int with a value of 50

Comment: It's not very clear by what you mean by "is there any point". You should use the method if the documented behaviour is what you require; otherwise, don't use it.

Comment: Or, are you asking if there is any point to using as opposed to *(some other method you're thinking of)*?

Comment: @AndyTurner I was wondering the point of this method if I can use Unary Numeric Promotion for `chars` and `Character.digit` for digits.

Comment: Numeric promotion certainly is not the same thing, as it produces a different value.  For looping as in your code example, getNumericValue is unneeded.  There probably are few real-world use cases for the getNumericValue method.

Comment: @VGR those examples is actually what I am after here, Can You provide some?

Comment: Honestly, I can’t think of a meaningful use case.  I guess it theoretically might be useful when parsing a data file with numbers in many locales, if such a thing even exists.

Answer (score 2):

`Character.getNumericValue` is designed to support number bases greater than 10. For example, in hexadecimal, the letters A to F are also digits representing 10 to 15. `Character.getNumericValue` extends this concept all the way to `z`: A is 10, B is 11, C is 12, ..., Z is 35 (case-insensitive). So it works for digits *and* letters. As far as I can tell from the docs, it also supports other numbering systems, hence the roman numeral you mentioned.

As for what the point is, well internationalization immediately comes to mind. Arabic numberals aren't the only numbering system, and if you have a UTF-16 character set, and a method called `Character.getNumericValue`, it makes sense that it shouldn't just be restricted to the English numbering system.

Comment: So is there a difference to `Character.digit`? EDIT `Character.getNumericValue('五')` returns `-1` so it is not working?

Comment: From what I can tell `Character.digit` is for "computer" numbers i.e. 0-9 and A-F that I mentioned in the first paragraph. `Character.getNumericValue` is for "real-world" numbers, hence the need to support not just multiple bases, but also multiple numeric systems. 
And I added that as a conceptual example, I didn't actually test it. I guess I should remove it.